# Using a faster sorting mechanism to sort in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting

Consider the following code:

```
 public List<Test> findAll(HashMap sortOrder) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Test.class);

    if (sortOrder != null) {
        Iterator iterator = sortOrder.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String value = (String) sortOrder.get(key);
            if (value != null && value.equals("asc")) {
                criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(key));
            } else {
                criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(key));

            }
        }
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

This results in a list where we get sorted results. Can I use colletion's sort to sort accordingly or comparator method?

Comment: Your question is not clear what you want to do.? above code gives you list of Test in sorted order, no sorting is performed on list, it just generate the query which returns you ordered collection. and in case of collection's sort or sorting by comparator is work on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Collections.sort()` if you already have a `Collection,` which implies that the dataset fits entirely into memory. You can't make that assumption with a query result. In any case the database is going to sort it a lot quicker than you can, especially if you are ordering by indexed columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose implementing this with a TreeMap, which has an implicit ordering, and defining the contained objects with the interface Comparable, so you have to define an int compare() method which will sort for you automatically.

In this way, you don't have to use all that code

Answer (score 0):

So you mean to say if I do something like this :

```
public List<Test> findAllColletion() {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
    List<Test> list = criteria.list();
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Test>() {
        public int compare(Testo1, Testo2) {
            return o1.getExternalRef().compareTo(o2.getExternalRef());
        }
    });

   return list;
}
```

Then this will be quicker than implementing order by right?